# Sftp virtualhosting based on the SNI server name?

Tags: sftp

I am thinking on the possibility of the virtualhosting of sftp based on the server name, which was given by the client with SNI. Is it possible? Does any similar already exist there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SNI is an extension of the TLS (SSL) protocol. SFTP does not use TLS as transport protocol, but uses SSH, thus SNI is not available.

You can of course change the content of the SFTP server based on the credentials provided (and `chroot` the environment).